# How To Do A Popup Context Menu Like DroneDeploys

Tags: dronedeploy

How can I include a popup context menu in my app, just like the ones DroneDeploy use?

What's the CSS, JS lib that you use???

I know how to do this using vanilla JavaScript, but I want it to look like yours, to keep the theme in tact!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the source and can see you are using Angular CDK's OverlayModule to provide popups.

I'm not using Angular, so I'll have to just style the popup so it looks like you themes myself.

Answer (score -1):

The doc is the best way to follow up in this case. There you can see what's possible or not. Did you see [this point](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/checklist.html)? Here you can follow a checklist to apply in your App and build App in Drone Deploy style. You'll need to follow another way to interact with users.